# C compiler cannot create executables

Tags: gcc, configure, gdb

Everything was right. I have installed gdb from github and installed in `/usr/local/bin`. After that i removed default `gdb(/usr/bin)` using the following command

```
sudo apt-get remove gdb
```

Now, when try to configure i am getting following errors:

```
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
```

It's look like c compiler issue. But i have gcc,g++ and build-essential installed. Even i did configure and make before the `gdb(github)` installation. My system is `ubuntu 14.04 (64bit)`. I also found that by including `'O3'` in CFLAGS it can be solved. But it's not working for me. Please help.

## EDIT

When i try to compile a simple c file using `gcc` (`gcc test.c`) i got this error:

```
/usr/local/bin/ld: this linker was not configured to use sysroots
```

I also tried to re-install `binutils`. But it didn't help.

Comment: Did you check the `config.log` (in the same directory as the configure script usually); it contains the detailed commands executed to test the compiler. And their output too. You can add them to your question if they didn't help you to solve to problem.

Comment: @Benoit I didn't find anything unusual in config.log and it's large enough too(4624 line)

Comment: Have you tried manually `gcc` ? If you are not a developer, go to [this site](http://groups.engin.umd.umich.edu/CIS/course.des/cis400/c/hworld.html), paste the code into a file like `test.c` and execute `gcc -o test test.c`. Do you get an executable called `test` which print "Hello world" ?

Comment: Where is the source package that you are trying to `./configure` located on your system? The `cannot create executables` message sometimes indicates that the filesystem doesn't support Unix-style permissions (e.g. NTFS).

Comment: @steeldriver It's not NTFS problem. I can assure you that.

Comment: @Benoit I have edited the question. Please take a look.

Comment: It looks like the `/usr/local/bin/ld` doesn't have the same capabilities as the `/usr/bin/ld` which is provided by the `binutils` package. Could you get rid of this `/usr/local/bin/ld` by, e.g., renaming it and retry the `gcc` test ? (to force the use of the default `ld` command)

Comment: Tip: don't mess with the compiler toolchain when you have no idea what you are doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to install the latest version of `gdb(7.8)` in ubuntu. But somehow `ld (part of binutil)` from `gdb` package is not supported by `ubuntu 14.04`. So i have to uninstall it. But there is no `gdb` uninstall script. So i did the following:

```
Step 1: edit /etc/environment and move /usr/local/bin to then end of the line. I let the system to load /usr/bin first.

Step 2: update path: source /etc/environment

Step 3: remove gdb files: sudo rm -rf /usr/local/bin/gdb* /usr/local/bin/ld

Step 4: re-install binutils: sudo apt-get install --reinstall binutils
```